# Time Complexity of a Top Down Merge Sort?

Tags: sorting, time, merge, complexity-theory

I understand that mergesort's time complexity is O(nLogn), however I am unable to arrive at this conclusion for its Top Down variant.

```
TopDownMerge(A[], iBegin, iMiddle, iEnd, B[])
{
i0 = iBegin, i1 = iMiddle;

// While there are elements in the left or right runs
for (j = iBegin; j < iEnd; j++) {
    // If left run head exists and is <= existing right run head.
    if (i0 < iMiddle && (i1 >= iEnd || A[i0] <= A[i1]))
        B[j] = A[i0];
        i0 = i0 + 1;
    else
        B[j] = A[i1];
        i1 = i1 + 1;    
    } 
}
```

I got this from the Wikipedia page, and the "if" statement is throwing me off, rather its conditions are driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry which kind of language is it? what's the problem ?

Comment: C++, I'm not sure how many times the if statement runs

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have blocked out is only *part* of the algorithm: the part that performs the merge.  The complexity for this portion is O(n). (The logn comes from the other half of the algorithm, where the array is repeatedly chopped into segments.)

First, let's define what the (somewhat cryptic) variables mean:

- `iBegin`, `iMiddle`, and `iEnd` indicate the working segment of `A`.  The left half (from `iBegin` to `iMiddle`) and the right half (from `iMiddle` to `iEnd`) are both sorted and ready to be merged together.
- `i0` is the index of the "next" variable in the **left** half of the working segment of `A`.
- `i1` is the index of the "next" variable in the **right** half of the working segment of `A`.
- `j` is the index of the next empty spot in working array `B`.

Each time through the loop, a single element is copied out of `A` and placed in array `B` at position `j`.  The `if` statement is responsible for determining whether the element should be taken from the left or the right half of the array.

The `if` statement performs (up to) three checks:

- If `i0 < iMiddle`, then there are still elements to process in the left half of the array.  If this is false, go to the `else` block and take the element from the right half of the array.
- If `i1 >= iEnd`, then there are no more elements to process in the right half of the array.  If this is true, enter the `if` block and take the element from the left half of the array.
- At this point, there must be some element left in both the left and right halves of the array.  Compare the two elements: if `A[i0] <= A[i1]`, take the next element from the left half; otherwise, take it from the right.

After the loop is over, the `if` statement will always have executed `j` times - once for each element that we copied from the original array segment to the working array.  Therefore, the amount of work to merge the two array segments together is proportional to the size of the array, i.e. O(n).